# Get the number of rows of a static table view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I have a static table view, created using a storyboard. I want to get its number of rows in code. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I know about is:

```
NSInteger rows = 0;
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [myTable numberOfSections]; ++i)
{
    rows += [myTable numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}
```